# Cisco 2900 Series Routers worth the price?

Tags: cisco, router

Just wondering if anyone has experience with the cisco 2911 or 2900 series routers?  I understand it is newer and similar to the 2811 but more robust.  The price difference is not that much more. I am curious as to why.  I am trying to determine if I should go with the 29xx or 28xx series for a medium sized company.   ISP load balancing and fail over is required.  T1 and ADSL lines already in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be tempted to stick with the 2800 platform.  It's older, more robust.. Less likely to be full of new untested bugs.  Give the 2900 series a while to get into the mainstream.

I seem to recall that the 29xx have the IOS 15.x software.  Also very new.  It took a long time before the number of bugs in 12.x became low, and the software became stable.

I wouldn't personally choose software or hardware close to the bleeding-edge for any other production environment, so I don't see why routing should be any different.

Comment: I've gone with the 2811.  It will definitely fits our needs and moreso.  Thank you for your recommendation.